# Will a closed set which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ always be only a union of finite number of closed intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A closed set is defined as follows:

> A subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is closed if every convergent sequence in $X$ converges to a point in $X$ itself. It is a generalization of closed intervals.

While I realize that it is a useful generalization of closed intervals for spaces other than $\mathbb{R}$, I want to know that for subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, is there an example of a closed set which cannot be described as a union of finite number of closed intervals (including single points, i.e. $[a,a]$)?

**EDIT:** Earlier, the question had not mentioned that it has to be a union of finite number of sets, but later I edited it to include that condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with "union of closed intervals" is that no definition of this type will in fact work.

Either you only allow finite unions
$$A = \bigcup_{i=1}^N [l_i, r_i]$$
and miss out on sets like
$$B = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty [3i, 3i + 1]$$
wich cannot be described as a finite union of (closed) intervals although it is closed

Or you permit them and declare
$$\mathbb Q = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty [q_i, q_i]$$
closed, wich it is not.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because after seeing all the answers, a question popped into my head which was "what if we allow union of countably infinite intervals" which would invalidate clever examples like $(a, b) =\bigcup_{a\in (a, b)}[a, a].$ and allow examples like $\mathbb{Z}$, but your example of $\mathbb{Q}$ puts it to rest

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha Note that the Cantor set (see my answer) is also a counterexample, the other way: it's a closed set that you can't write as a union of even countably many closed intervals.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The same holds for $B$, doesn't it? If I didn't mess up, $B$ is an infinite "zebra crossing". The Cantor set is nicer though in the sense that it's compact. A similarly "nice" counter-example would be $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$

Comment: $B$ can be (indeed, is) written as a countable union of closed intervals - I'm talking about an example of a closed set which is not a union of countably many intervals. And $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0, 1]$ is a counterexample in the other direction - a set which *can* be written as a countable union of closed intervals, but *isn't* closed.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah I see. Very clever! (+1)

Comment: That is: the Cantor set is a counterexample to the claim "Every closed set can be written as the union of countably many closed intervals," while $\mathbb{Q}$ is a counterexample to the claim "Every set which is a union of countably many closed intervals is closed."

Answer (score 2):

**Any** set is a union of closed intervals: $$A=\bigcup_{a\in A}[a, a].$$ (Remember that a union of closed sets need not be closed!)

---

EDIT: if you want a union of *finitely many* closed intervals only, then it is no longer true that every set has such a form, and indeed there are closed sets which cannot be so written. A couple basic examples are:

- $\mathbb{Z}$.
- The [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set). (This one can't even be written as a *countable* union of closed sets. It's also [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space), which is a nice property - especially in light of the example $\mathbb{Z}$ above, which might feel like cheating since it "goes to infinity.")

Comment: I disagree, you can't describe an open set $(a, b)$ as a union of closed intervals. Perhaps I should add that it has to be a union of finite number of terms. It will invalidate your answer, sorry about that, but what you answered wasn't really what I meant to ask

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha You are wrong:$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{c\in(a,b)}[c,c].$$

Comment: Just take $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} [2n,2n+1]$.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha I've updated my answer.

Comment: I understand the Cantor set now, it's a very nice example.

Answer (score 1):

The set$$\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{n}}\left\{\frac1n\right\}$$is a closed susbset of $\mathbb R$ which cannot be expressed as the union of a finite family of closed intervals.

Comment: +1 for interesting example, I spent some time trying to make a sequence in this set which would have a limit outside this set because I couldn't accept that it was closed at first glance